# Send an array of objects to the server side using AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Below is my snippet. First, I loop through each table row, get the first, second and third text and push it to the array named 'files' (like multi dimensional array, you can see its console log)

```js
var files = []
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr').each(function(){
    files.push({ 'name' : $(this).find('td:first-child').text(), 'age' : $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text(), 'identity' : $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text() });
  
  });
  console.log(files);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Human</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>Human</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>Alien</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and then send it using Ajax post

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/page.php',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data: { id : files },
    success:function(e){}
});
```

and then in the back end side

```
public function rr(Request $request){
    $count = '';
    //loop
    foreach($request->id as $d){
       $count.=$d->identity;
    }
    dd(var_dump($count));
}
```

If I dump the request named 'id' here's what I get

> array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Name 1" ["age"]=>
>   string(3) "22" ["identity"]=> string(18) "Human" } [1]=> array(4) {
>   ["name"]=> string(14) "Name 2" ["age"]=> string(3) "18 ["identity"]=>
>   string(14) "Human"  } [2]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Name 3"
>   ["age"]=> string(3) "40" ["identity"]=> string(7) "Alien" } }

but seems like its not working, instead it gives me this error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Any help, clues, ideas, suggestions, recommendations please?

Comment: dump the request at first...

Comment: @vitr: please see my updated post.

Comment: did you try this $count.=$d["identity"];

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: wooh! thank you, it works. that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$count.=$d=>identity** to  **$count.=$d["identity"]**

```
  public function rr(Request $request){
    $count = '';
   //loop
    foreach($request->id as $d){
      $count.=$d["identity"];
   }
    dd(var_dump($count));
 }
```